# edge betweenness community cut off point

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

I am trying to figure out how to set a cutoff point for the edge betweenness community algorithm in igraph. The example code below returns 24 splits, what would i have to do to return 10 for example?

```
g01 <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 1/10, directed = FALSE)

bc <- edge.betweenness.community(g01)
plot(g01, vertex.color=membership(bc))
bc
```

Comment: It is returning 24 groups, because the default is to return the split with the highest modularity score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `cutat(...)`:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)     # for reproducibility
g01 <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 1/10, directed = FALSE)

bc <- edge.betweenness.community(g01)
cut <- cutat(bc,10)
colors <- rainbow(10)
plot(g01, vertex.color=colors[cut])
```

[image]

Your`bc` is a hierarchical  `community` object, which can be cut to give n clusters using `cutat(bc,n)`. This is analogous to using `cutree(...)` with hierarchical clusters.

I only used rainbow colors because otherwise the main color is black.